# How does enumerate(zip(*k_fold(dataset, folds))) work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If we have:

```
a = ['a', 'aa', 'aaa']
b = ['b', 'bb', 'bbb']

for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
    print (i, x, y)
```

then the code prints:

```
0 a b
1 aa bb
2 aaa bbb
```

To iterate over *all* elements of the two lists, they must have the same size.

Now, if we have the following snippet:

```
for fold, (train_idx, test_idx, val_idx) in enumerate(zip(*k_fold(dataset, folds))):
    pass
```

where `len(dataset)` = 1000 and `folds` = 3, then how does the code works in terms of `*k_fold(dataset, folds)`?

**EDIT:**

I add the reference of the snippet about which my question is, it is line 31 of [this code](https://github.com/camlsys/degree-quant/blob/main/reddit_binary/train_eval.py).

Comment: what does the k_fold(dataset, folds) function return?

Comment: Python’s zip() function is defined as zip(*iterables). The function takes in iterables as arguments and returns an iterator. This iterator generates a series of tuples containing elements from each iterable. zip() can accept any type of iterable, such as files, lists, tuples, dictionaries, sets, and so on.

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/

Comment: @plpm the point is we don't know what the function `k_fold` is -- it's not a python built-in function and you haven't shown us where you have imported it from.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe I added the reference of the code in my question under EDIT.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe so it returns return train_indices, test_indices, val_indices

Comment: so the kfold() function is defined from line 120. what is your question? do you want to know what kfold means? do you want to know what enumerate/zip does? happy to explain either one, but not wasting time explaining everything for no reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Python's `enumerate` function

Enumeration is used to iterate through an iterable whilst keeping an integer count of the number of iterations, so:

```py
>>> for number, value in enumerate(["a", "b", "c"]):
...     print(number, value)
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

## Python's `zip` function

The built-in function `zip` is used to combine two iterables like so:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4]
>>> list(zip(a, b))
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

When `zip` is provided with iterables of different length, then it returns a `zip` object with the length of the shortest iterable. So:

```py
>>> a = [1, 2, 5, 6]
>>> b = [3, 4]
>>> list(zip(a, b))
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

## Python's unpacking operator

Python uses the `*` to unpack iterables. Looking through the GitHub repository, it seems that `k_fold` returns a tuple with 3 elements. This is so that they can pass the values that the `k_fold` function returns into the iterable.

Comment: Thank you, the last paragraph is what I was looking for.

Comment: I though queston was: where len(dataset) = 1000 and folds = 3, then how does the code works in terms of *k_fold(dataset, folds)?

Answer (score 0):

bonus example:

```
a = [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10 , 11]
b = [3, 4, 12, 13 ]
c = [ 14, 15 ]
for i in enumerate(zip(a, b, c)):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
(0, (1, 3, 14))
(1, (2, 4, 15))   -----> like they are fold, (train_idx, test_idx, val_idx)
```

not sure about what train_idx, test_idx, val_idx are in the code on github:

train_idx, test_idx val_idx are lists don't know with what they are filled though !

Comment: its not for you, I was trying too follow without knowing anything about sklearn and torch